# Extracting RGB channels in OpenCV under C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV to convert image data captured using an IDS uEye camera into a useful format, using the following code:

```
IplImage* tmpImg = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width,height),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
tmpImg->imageData = pFrameBuffer[k];
frame = cv::cvarrToMat(tmpImg);
```

This works perfectly - I can then use `imwrite(filename,frame);` further downstream to write the processed images out as a sensible format. I would ideally like to be able to save the RGB channels as separate 'grayscale' image files, but I don't understand the OpenCV documentation regarding single-channel operations. Can anyone suggest a means of accomplishing this? Preferably it's not overly computationally expensive (looping over an image pixel-by pixel isn't an option - I'm working with 60-230fps video at up to 1280x1064, and all the processing has to be done at the point of capture).

Running the latest Debian Testing if that makes any difference (I don't think it should).

Comment: also, stop using IplImage. Use Mat instead, and the C++ functions!

Comment: I'm not a massive OpenCV person - could you give me an example of how to accomplish the same end without IplImage?

Comment: something like `Mat frame(Size(width, height), CV_8UC3, pData)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have a `cv::Mat` object it's pretty simple:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> grayPlanes;
cv::split(frame, grayPlanes);

cv::imwrite("blue.png", grayPlanes[0]);
cv::imwrite("green.png", grayPlanes[1]);
cv::imwrite("red.png", grayPlanes[2]);
```

The split function can directly write to a standard vector and you don't really have to think about memory management and other stuff.